# dataframe create new column of integer julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to add a new column Y to a dataframe of type `Float64` using another column Z of integer and an array X of type `Array{Float64,1}`.

When I run the command:

```
df[:Y] = map(z->X[z],df[:Z])
```

I get that that type of `df[:X]` is `Any`.

How can I change the type of `df[:Y]` to Float?

Example:

```
df = DataFrame( Z  = @data([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ) 
X = [1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5]
df[:Y] = map(z->X[z],df[:Z])
```

then `typeof(df[:Y])` returns `DataArrays.DataArray{Any,1}`.

Comment: Alexander Morley: Thanks so much!

Comment: welcome to SO. Please mark Alexander's answer as accepted if it has indeed answered your question (and also in general consider voting it and any other answers that you find it a useful, interesting or noteworthy contribution in its own right). This helps future readers skip to the right / useful answers, flags answered questions properly as answered in the database, and rewards the answerer with 'reputation' for their effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df[:Y] = convert(DataArray{Float64,1}, map(z->X[z],df[:Z]))`

Like that, or were you looking for something more?